# Spans inside paragraph per line

Tags: html, css

I have:

`name: james`

but I want to be shown as:

```
name:
james
```

[Here's a live example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/NNpqq/)

**HTML** markup:

```
<p>
<span class="bla">name:</span>
<span class="bla">james</span>
</p>
```

**CSS** markup:

```
.bla {
 display: inline-block;   
}​
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`inline-block` isn't going to achieve what you are after, if you are wanting to do this by adding styles to the `.bla` class. Try changing it to `display:block` instead.

See my Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/1/

```
.bla {
 display: block;   
}​
```

Or you can add some markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/5/

```
<p>
    <span class="bla">name:</span> <br />
    <span class="bla">james</span>
</p>
​
```

Comment: oh god, it was so easy! thx, btw, just to get some knowledge, what if the 2nd span doesnt have the same class always? I.E.: `<span class="bla">name:</span>
    <span class="bla2">james</span>`

Comment: Well you can reference it from it's parent, if that is going to be consistent. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/6/

Comment: Without <br /> : http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/6/

With <br />: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/7/

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
<p>
<span class="bla">name:</span><br/>
<span class="bla">james</span>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/NNpqq/

Comment: Why don't you want to use <br/> ? It's a line break, it's mean to be used like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
.bla {
 display:block;   
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what breaks are for good sir.

```
<p>
    name:<br/>james
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NNpqq/4/

Comment: You should've said so :p that's how you do html newlines

Answer (score 1):

Just put:

```
<p>name:<br/>James</p>
```

... and you can get rid of the CSS. If you need to adjust line-height, apply it on the "br" tag via CSS.

As a sidenote, don't repeat the "bla" class in your HTML markup (unless you have a specific reason to do so). You can reach it through the `<p>` parent to reduce markup and make your code cleaner:

```
CSS:
p.bla {}
p.bla span {}

HTML:
<p class="bla">
  <span></span> 
  <span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: actually i need the `css`, this is a very small example of what i'm trying to achieve, most of the `<span>` need the `bla` class, but not all of them, and i need them to be on separate lines. Thx for your contribution to the question!